# NullPointerException on static SharedPreferences variable

Tags: android

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce this error myself, but the NullPointerException is reported in the Google Play Console on this line in some POJO:

```
String mypref = MainActivity.prefs.getString("mypref", null);
```

The relevant part of MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        ...
    }
```

MainActivity is the activity listed first in the manifest and is the target activity on app launch:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The error seems to be surfacing very seldom and very few users seem to be affected. However, I still would like to understand what's going on here. The prefs variable is accessed in the same way in other places throughout my app which are not being reported in the Google Play Console.

My take on it is that the prefs variable itself must be null. That would mean the onCreate method of MainActivity was not executed. How could this be possible?

Comment: Do you have more than one Activity?

Comment: Yes, three in total.

Comment: Well, if MainActivity is destroyed so is your static field..

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. A static field should be unaffected by the destruction of an instance of the class.

Comment: The Activity will be garbage collected. A static field does not prevent that once the class is unloaded from the ClassLoader.

Comment: Sure, the static field does not prevent the destruction of the activity, but the value of the static field itself should be unaffected by the destruction of the activity.

Comment: you should not use static fields in activities unless they are compile time constants. Your problems will go away if you properly manage this SharedPreferences instance in a class that's not affected by a view's lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

When users leave your app, the Android OS can terminate your app's process. When it does this, anything that is **not** saved as part of an `onSaveInstanceState()` callback will be lost. This includes `static` fields.

In your particular situation, there's no need for this static variable anyway. The only thing you gain by doing things the way you're doing them now is that you can use `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` to determine the preference store's name. If you use `Context.getSharedPreferences()` and pass that name manually, you can access the same preferences store from anywhere in your app.